# Set default option as "No" for custom select attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-attributes, option

I have used below code to generate a custom select attribute.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', "best_seller_flag", array(
    'type'       => 'int',
    'group'      => 'Flags',
    'input'      => 'select',
    'label'      => 'Best seller flag',
    'default'    => '',
    'sort_order' => 2,
    'required'   => false,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'option'     => array (
        'values' => array(
            0 => 'No',
            1 => 'Yes'
        )
    ),
));

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', /* another attribute */);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', /* another attribute */);
```

The attribute was created successfully but by default "No" option is not selected. It is showing in admin panel as shown in the below image:

[image]

---

When I inspect the element, I can see the following code (*related to a single attribute*)

```
<select class=" select" name="product[best_seller_flag]" id="best_seller_flag">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="156">No</option>
    <option value="157">Yes</option>
</select>
```

As you can see in above code, **the values of options are not 0 and 1, instead they are some numbers like 156 and 157**.

I think this is the main reason to why the `'default' => ''` is not working. (*even tried `'default' => '0'`*)

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the boolean source model instead of the table source model you can easily define the default 0:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', "best_seller_flag", array(
    'type'       => 'int',
    'group'      => 'Flags',
    'input'      => 'select',
    'label'      => 'Best seller flag',
    'default'    => '0',
    'sort_order' => 2,
    'required'   => false,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'source'     => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'
));
```

Comment: yup this worked.. thanks :) a small doubt.. can I write my own html in this properties of custom attribute? if yes, what property I should use?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Maybe better expand the original post or write a new question?

Comment: hi @Vinai using above code with default value set to '0' but on product page in admin it displays 'Yes' as default selected value (until I save it to No), it there a way in installation script that it shows 'No' by default?